# Train from Istanbul To Izmit and back

Tags: trains, turkey, istanbul

We are traveling to Istanbul, Turkey next month and we would like to take a day to visit Izmit.

With that plan in mind what we would like to do is travel from Istanbul (european side) to Izmit in the morning ~7am and return in the evening ~9pm.

Can you tell me how we can make this journey, preferably by train and where can we buy tickets from and what the approximate price is?

Comment: http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Istanbul/%C4%B0zmit

Comment: Yiu'll need to take a ferry first to the other side, then take a train from there to Izmit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, due to the major infrastructure work (for high speed trains) train schedules from Istanbul to the rest of Turkey are cancelled. I am not completely sure, so be advised.

If I were you, I'd take a bus from the city center, as the tickets are very cheap and, relative to trains, buses are more comfortable and faster.

You can have a look at the following sites:

www.pamukkale.com.tr
www.kamilkoc.com.tr
www.obilet.com

As it's a short distance, I am pretty sure you can easily obtain a ticket at the last minute. All bus companies have shuttle buses that take you from the point of ticket sale to the transfer hub, where you start your journey. Those shuttles are free of charge.

Bus tickets should be around 20 Turkish Lira.

Hope I could help.

Comment: An hour and half is not really far for Turkish people. It's a big country and considering that there are people coming from İzmit to İstanbul everyday for work, there are more possibilities for transportation than for example to Trabzon.

Answer (score 0):

I have just check it online and seen that you can take the train but the only departure location in Istanbul seems Pendik (in Asian Side). It might be difficult for you.

As mentioned before, bus is a good alternative solution. Or, there is a company called blablacar.com. If you are not more than 4 I think, you can check the website and find a guy with a private car who can take you to Izmit. It is cheaper than bus tickets. I think you only share the cost of gasoline. I have never used it but heard a lot. You may want to take a look.